# why does find alter matching behaviour when -exec is appended here?

Tags: shell, find

Consider the following:

```
/tmp/tmp.DkL0R4v7RR$ find . -regex '\./spam' -o -regex '\./eggs'
./spam
./eggs
/tmp/tmp.DkL0R4v7RR$ find . -regex '\./spam' -o -regex '\./eggs' -exec ls \{} \;
./eggs
/tmp/tmp.DkL0R4v7RR$ find . -regex '\./spam' -o -regex '\./eggs' | xargs ls
./eggs  ./spam
```

Why does the appended `-exec` alter the behaviour so that only the second regex is matched?

Comment: yes, partly. I always guessed this and tried `find . "(-regex '\./spam' -o -regex '\./eggs')" -exec ls \{} \;` but to no avail. It’s not entirely clear to me why it has to be escaped like that, but … well, thanks, anyway

Comment: The `(` and `)` need to be escaped because they're part of the shell syntax (for starting subshells and other uses), `{}` doesn't need to be escaped in some shells, though.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But I do not understand why "( … )" does not work resp. why `'('` and `\)` need to be single arguments on the command line.

Comment: `find` is not like `sed` (or `awk`) where you can provide code as a string and the tool parses it. `find` expects operands as separate arguments. It performs neither word splitting nor quote removal; these are jobs of the shell.